# Wicket Model object contains a List - how to bind this properly

Tags: model, wicket

I have the following model class (simplified)

```
class A{
  private String name;
  private List<B> items;
}

class B{
  private long from;
  private long to;
}
```

Moreover I have Form that gets the class A bound by a CompoundPropertyModel. If I want to display a TextField that is bound to the name field, I just add

```
new TextField("name");
```

and that's all. But how do I correctly bind this list of items? For class B I also have FormComponent that overrides the convertInput, because I want to do some calculations before assigning the values to the fields from, to. 
I have tried (Property)ListView, but both seem not to work (or I use them in a wrong way).

Thank you and kind regards,

M.

Comment: Are you displaying the values from the List<B> in any kind of repeater? which one? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using

```
Form form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(modelObject));
form.add(new ListView("items"));
```

is equivalent to

```
Form form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(modelObject));
form.add(new ListView("items", new PropertyModel(modelObject, "items"));
```

The ListView's Model will be backed by the `items` property of the CPM's model object. 
Remember to override `populateItem`, in which the `ListItem`'s model object will be each one of the elements in the `List`.

You can perform your calculations on the `items` property of the backing model object. If you don't want to modify the model object's property, you shouldn't be using CPM to bind the `items` property, and implement a `Model` that provides the modified `List` (might be useful if you want these calculations to be updated at every page rendering, as in ajax refreshing.

This Wicket wiki page shows the usage of `ListView`: [ListView and other repeaters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/ListView+and+other+repeaters)